# Simple PyQt demo from book doesn't work

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm brand new to GUI programming under Python and just got the book "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT" by Summerfield.  The very first simple example ("pop-up alert in 25 lines") on page 112 works, but my attempt to exactly replicate the second example ("an expression evaluator in 30 lines") on page 116  produces only a blank window, with no visible fields for either entry or output and not even a window title.  This is under Mac OS X 10.8.5  using the latest Enthought Canopy 64-bit Python installation (1.2.0.1610)

The complete contents of PyQtdemo.pyw is

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
class Form(QDialog):
    def _init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an expression and press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updateUi)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")

    def updateUi(self):
        try:
            text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
            self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s</b>" % (text, eval(text)))
        except:
            self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is invalid!</font>" % text)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
print dir(app)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

It seems to me there are only the following possibilities:

1. there's a typo in my code that I've overlooked;
2. there's something wrong with how I'm invoking the script (e.g., "python PyQtdemo.pyw");
3. there's something wrong with my PyQt 4.10.3-1 installation;
4. there's an error in the book.

Comment: I suspect possibility #1, since `updateUi()` should be a method of the `Form` class and needs to be indented accordingly.

Comment: You're right that that method should have been indented (now fixed), but it seems not to have changed the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo in your code.

The `Form.__init__` method is missing an initial underscore, and so it never gets called.

(PS: This also explains why the incorrect indentation of the `updateUi` method doesn't raise an `AttributeError` when it's referenced in `self.connect`).